# Is there a way to copy an excel worksheet to multiple workbooks in onedrive?

Tags: vba, onedrive

I know there's a way to do it with google sheets but I'm wonder if there's any way to do it with OneDrive? Maybe with VBA?

Comment: In whose OneDrive?  You can use VBA to open each workbook, copy in the sheet and save the file.

Comment: The all the files are stored within my onedrive (with an organization). The files that need to be updated are shared to other users within the organization

Comment: Your OneDrive likely has a local folder mapped - eg for me it's `C:\Users\[username]\OneDrive - CompanyName\ `   If you're having problems with this task then you need to explain more exactly what problem you're facing - what do you not know how to do?  If you're not familiar with VBA then this is not really the place for a tutorial - it's more for questions around existing code with errors/problems.